# Performance issues with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, performance, drawing, core-graphics

I have serious performance issues in my game. I'm developing a jigsaw puzzle game. I cut down an image into smaller images, create a UIView for each jigsaw piece and assign each image into it's own UIView's CALayer.

Then a I create random UIBezier paths for the shapes as masks and assign them into CAShapeLayers and then I assign the shape layers to my UIView.layer.mask properties.

It all works like a charm up to the point when I try to move the jigsaw pieces. I detect touches and move the appropriate pieces' center property (CGPoint).

But it is sooo slow and "laggy" when I move a piece over other pieces.

I googled a lot, tried calling setNeedsDisplayInRect: my container view etc.
Also I found, that these methods redraw the whole thing and I dont need to redraw, I need only to move the pieces. And I've found that animating is a good approach, since it uses methods built up on OpenGL. So I tried animating (moving) the pieces using the UIView class'method in my jigsaw piece object (subclass of UIView):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x - _previousPoint.x, touchLocation.y - _previousPoint.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0
                 animations:^(void){
                     self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + offset.x, self.center.y + offset.y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
_previousPoint = touchLocation;   
}
```

But it also didn't do the trick.

Does anyone have an idea how to improve the performance of this?

I still think that the "move only" approach would be the solution (not redrawing every frame, since redrawing is very expensive). But I don't know how to implement that.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you triggering a redraw? If you just change the center point the view will be moved without redrawing (as standard).

Comment: That's the thing, I only move the center so I believe I don't trigger the redraw

Comment: Ok, I did some experimenting and I found that when I set jigSawPiece.layer.shouldRasterize = YES, then it's almost 2x faster! 
But still not acceptable...